# Usability issue for navigator.geolocation: how to know if the user is being asked for location?

Tags: html, geolocation

Does HTML's `navigator.geolocation` have an event handler for 'Currently asking the user if they will share their location'?

I would like to show some text instructing the user to share their location *if and only if* they are actually being asked to share their location.

Currently I have this code, but it's broken.

It looks smooth the first time, but the second time (when the browser knows this is a trusted site, so doesn't ask the user about sharing their location), 'Share your location' flashes up quickly when the page loads, then disappears behind the map.

```
    // map.js
    function gpsSuccess() { 
        // We have a location - although we don't know whether this is 
        // because the user has already agreed to share with this domain,
        // or whether they have just this second been asked. 
        $('#sharelocation').hide();
        // load map, etc
    }
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(gpsSuccess, gpsFail);
    }   

    // map.html
    <div id="sharelocation">Share your location</div>
    <div id="map" class="hidden"></div>
```

Any suggestions for a smooth way to give the user some instructions in the body of the page *if and only if* they are actually being asked to share their location?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider not showing the "Share Location" message unless the failure callback gets executed.

```
function gpsFail() {
  $('#sharelocation').show();
}
```

You can include a message in the sharelocation block which explains how to enable location sharing, what you'll do with the information, etc.

Comment: That doesn't work, I'm afraid - at least on Chrome, the failure callback isn't executed while the browser is still waiting for a response from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might just have a timing issue with the brief delay between getCurrentPosition and your callback. What if you delay the show by a second or so? (I don't know what the jquery-specific method is) Keep a reference to the task so in gpsSuccess you can call clearTimeout with it.